# Aggregating in pandas with two different identification columns

Tags: python, pandas, sum, logic, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate a dataset with purchases, I have shortened the example in this post to keep it simple. The purchases are distinguished based on two different columns used to identify both customer and transaction. The reference refers to the same transaction, while the ID refers to the type of transaction.

I want to sum these records based on ID, however while keeping in mind the reference and not double-counting the size. The example I provide clears it up.

What I tried so far is:

- df_new = df.groupby(by = ['id'], as_index=False).agg(aggregate)
- df_new = df.groupby(by = ['id','ref'], as_index=False).agg(aggregate)

Let me know if you have any idea what I can do in pandas, or otherwise in Python.

This is basically what I have,

| Name | Reference | Side | Size | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 0 | BUY | 2400 | 0 |
| Alex | 0 | BUY | 2400 | 0 |
| Alex | 0 | BUY | 2400 | 0 |
| Alex | 1 | BUY | 3000 | 0 |
| Alex | 1 | BUY | 3000 | 0 |
| Alex | 1 | BUY | 3000 | 0 |
| Alex | 2 | SELL | 4500 | 1 |
| Alex | 2 | SELL | 4500 | 1 |
| Sam | 3 | BUY | 1500 | 2 |
| Sam | 3 | BUY | 1500 | 2 |
| Sam | 3 | BUY | 1500 | 2 |

What I am trying to achieve is the following,

| Name | Side | Size | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | BUY | 5400 | 0 |
| Alex | SELL | 4500 | 1 |
| Sam | BUY | 1500 | 2 |

P.S. the records are not duplicates of each other, what I provide is a simplified version, but in reality 'Name' is 20 more columns identifying each row.

P.S. P.S. My solution was to first aggregate by Reference then by ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop_duplicates`, `groupby`, and `agg`:

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(['Name', 'Side']).agg({'Size': 'sum', 'ID': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   Name  Side  Size  ID
0  Alex   BUY  5400   0
1  Alex  SELL  4500   1
2   Sam   BUY  1500   2
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is an example I made for the post, and in the real (larger) dataset with more columns they are not duplicates, but each row is a unique transaction.

Comment: Okay, try removing the `.drop_duplicates()` part. Does it work as expected then? e.g. new_df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Side']).agg({'Size': 'sum', 'ID': 'first'}).reset_index()

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it does not do what is expected. Since this way it sums up 16,200 for Alex and ID = 0.

Comment: The solution that I came to in the end was to first aggregate by Reference then by ID.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** richardec's solution is better as this will also sum the ID column.

This double groupby should achieve the output you want, as long as names are unique.

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'Reference']).max().groupby(['Name', 'Side']).sum()
```

**Explanation:** First we group by Name and Reference to get the following dataframe. The ".max()" could just as well be ".min()" or ".mean()" as it seems your data will have the same size per unique transaction:

| Name | Reference | Side | Size | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 0 | BUY | 2400 | 0 |
|  | 1 | BUY | 3000 | 0 |
|  | 2 | SELL | 4500 | 1 |
| Sam | 3 | BUY | 1500 | 2 |

Then we group this data by Name and Side with a ".sum()" operation to get the final result.

| Name | Side | Size | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | BUY | 5400 | 0 |
|  | SELL | 4500 | 1 |
| Sam | BUY | 1500 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

Just drop duplicates first and then aggregate with a list

something like this should do (not tested)

I always like to reset the index after

i.e

`df.drop_duplicates().groupby(["Name","Side","ID"]).sum()["Size"].reset_index()`

or

```py
# stops the double counts
df_dropped = df.drop_duplicates()
# groups by all the fields in your example
df_grouped = df_dropped.groupby(["Name","Side","ID"]).sum()["Size"]
# resets the 3 indexes created with above
df_reset = df_grouped.reset_index()
```